# server 2016 active directory and hyper-v same server

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016, failovercluster

I am getting ready to move my production environment from server 2012 R2 to server 2016

I want to do a clean install and in doing some inventory really only have two server I can use for staging, I want to be able to do a clean install.

I have read a couple articles about what is best practice for installing active directory and hyper-v same server.

My application is very light weight ant this will be a staggered migration, so my plan is to use two server (2016 datacenter), cluster them, add the 2012 guests one by one (rolling upgrade), and then when clean add them to the server 2016 I have in production.

What i would like to do is add AD DS to my two servers create a sub-domain replicate AD, and add also add the hyper-v role, along with DNS Server, Failover Clustering, File and Storage Services, Multipath I/O

Would there be any conflicts.

Comment: Hyper-V Hosts should only host the Hyper-V Role. Install your AD on a virtual machine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Having 2-node cluster, it's beneficial to have at least 2 AD DC VM's each located on a separated host. In case of a host failure, you will ensure the AD is up and running. The AD running on a VM also allows you granularly maintain AD and Hyper-V host. Microsoft recommends to run AD either on a Hyper-V VM or/and on a dedicated physical host. It's not recommended to run Hyper-V role and AD on the same system.

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/resource-library/useful-tips-for-setting-up-microsoft-active-directory-domain-controllers

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/a65d39f4-798a-432b-896a-543d51ff9038/hyperv-role-and-active-directory-service-in-same-server?forum=winservergen